# `conda-forge` fails to find existing shared lib in post-build step

Tags: conda

I am drafting an *MS Visual Studio Code* package for `conda-forge` ([the source](https://github.com/didenko/conda-recipes/blob/vscode_draft/recipes/vscode/meta.yaml)) and it fails to find libraries at the post-build step, even though the libraries are present at exactly the paths where `conda build .` looks for them:

```
[vlad@localhost vscode]$ conda build .
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Attempting to finalize metadata for vscode
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for vscode
BUILD START: ['vscode-1.23.1-0.tar.bz2']
Source cache directory is: /home/vlad/conda/conda-bld/src_cache
Found source in cache: vscode-stable_1.23.1_linux-x64_f3d1d1bf9d.tar.gz
Extracting download
source tree in: /home/vlad/conda/conda-bld/vscode_1528047341094/work

Resource usage statistics from building vscode:
   Process count: 1
   CPU time: unavailable
   Memory: 1.5M
   Disk usage: 215.0K
   Time elapsed: 0:00:02.1

Packaging vscode
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging vscode
Packaging vscode-1.23.1-0
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging vscode-1.23.1-0
number of files: 5627
Skipping binary relocation logic
WARNING (vscode,vscode/libffmpeg.so): did not find - or even know where to look for: /lib64/libm.so.6
WARNING (vscode,vscode/libffmpeg.so): did not find - or even know where to look for: /lib64/libc.so.6
WARNING (vscode,vscode/libffmpeg.so): did not find - or even know where to look for: /lib64/libpthread.so.0
WARNING (vscode,vscode/libffmpeg.so): did not find - or even know where to look for: /lib64/librt.so.1
WARNING (vscode,vscode/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/gc-signals/build/Release/gcsignals.node): did not find - or even know where to look for: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
WARNING (vscode,vscode/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/gc-signals/build/Release/gcsignals.node): did not find - or even know where to look for: /lib64/libc.so.6
WARNING (vscode,vscode/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/gc-signals/build/Release/gcsignals.node): did not find - or even know where to look for: /lib64/libpthread.so.0
..................................
..................................
..................................
..................................

[vlad@localhost vscode]$ ll /lib64/libm.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 12 May 27 15:10 /lib64/libm.so.6 -> libm-2.17.so
[vlad@localhost vscode]$ ll /lib64/libm-2.17.so 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1139680 Apr 10 04:24 /lib64/libm-2.17.so
[vlad@localhost vscode]$
```

As it is, the recipe is rather bare, without relocation and other complications. Why would it fail to find an object to which `conda` has a correct path? I did not think `conda` changes root to its destination - am I wrong?